# subprocess.check_call command called not using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, shell

I'm running the following command using subprocess.check_call

['/home/user/anaconda3/envs/hum2/bin/bowtie2-build', '-f', '/media/user/extra/tmp/subhm/sub_humann2_temp/sub_custom_chocophlan_database.ffn', '/media/user/extra/tmp/subhm/sub_humann2_temp/sub_bowtie2_index', ' --threads 8']

But for some reason, it ignores the --threads argument and runs on one thread only. I've checked outside of python with the same command that the threads are launched. This only happens when calling from subprocess, any idea on how to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `'--threads 8'` and not `'--threads',  '8'`. Although it could be `'--threads=8'` but I don't know the command.